# Error in Deploying azure function app to Azure using arm template in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

The github url that I am using json file is https://github.com/morsh/functions. Here I am trying to deploy function apps in Azure but facing issue as below

```
Here's the error detail:
{
"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one.",
"Target": null,
"Details": [
{
"Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one."
},
{
"Code": "BadRequest"
},
{
"ErrorEntity": {
"ExtendedCode": "59314",
"MessageTemplate": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one.",
"Parameters": [],
"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one."
}
}
],
"Innererror": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error hints you should create your app service plan in another resource group. try that and it should fix everything.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

Answer (score 0):

You can't have mixed Windows and Linux Web Apps in the same resource group unfortunately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations